# Not able to detect web element or hybrid element on using uiautomator2 in capabilities of appium

Tags: ruby, appium, android-uiautomator, appium-android

App automation flow is working fine on using uiautomator, but on adding uiautomator2 in capabilities it's not able to detect the elements on hybrid and web pages of an app.

```
require 'appium_lib'
require 'pry'

def caps
  {
      caps: {
          deviceName: "nexus",
          platformName: "Android",
          app: (File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "googlerelease.apk")),
          appPackage: "com.redmond.android",
          newCommandTimeout: "3600",
          autoGrantPermissions: true,
          automationName: "UiAutomator2"

      }
  }
end

Appium::Driver.new(caps, true)
Appium.promote_appium_methods Object
```

Comment: which appium server version are you using? try to update your appium server to latest stable version

Comment: I'm using the latest version i.e. appium 1.10.0

Comment: It is working now trick is I used xpath instead of id in hybrid pages